# Forecasting Future Values of Time Series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, markov-process

I am working with the R programming language. In particular, I am using "Markov Switching Models" for the purpose modelling more complicated dataset with varying degrees of volatility. For this problem, I am using the "MSwM" package in R:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSwM/MSwM.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSwM/vignettes/examples.pdf

I am following the first example from the "vignettes":

```
#load library
library(MSwM)

#load data
data(example)

#plot data
plot(ts(example))
```

[image]

```
#fit basic model
mod=lm(y~x,example)

#fit markov switching model:

mod.mswm=msmFit(mod,k=2,p=1,sw=c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),control=list(parallel=FALSE))
```

The above code successfully creates the model - 2 "Regimes" have been identified:

[image]

**Question:** I checked the documentation of this package, and there does not seem to be any functions that allow you to predict future values of this time series. I did some research and it seems like the "Markov Switching Model" should allow you to predict future values of a time series, e.g. : [How to forecast a Markov Switching Model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90448/how-to-forecast-a-markov-switching-model)

OR:

[image]

However, there does not seem to be a straightforward way to do this in R. Can someone please suggest how to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Questions that are only about software are off-topic here. You seem to have at least one answer to how to do this above (i.e. by simulation), so could you clarify exactly what it is you're having an issue with? The Markov switching models from package `MSwM` are state space models, and the procedure for simulating from such models is typically very simple. Computing the exact conditional expected value is usually more involved.

Comment: @ Chris Haug: Thank you for your reply! I am having difficulty understanding how to set up this simulation procedure. Using the R programming language, is there a straightforward way (e.g. built in functions) that can be used to easily predict future values of the time series using the Markov Switching Models? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @ Chris Haug: Can you please help me get started?